# Let's Encrypt 404 error on Google Cloud - Compute Engine - VM Instance

Tags: ssl, https, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, google

I'm setting up my Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Google's Compute Engine.  I have Apache installed & it's already hosting my domain on HTTP, and I'd like to enable HTTPS.

Steps taken so far:

- change the IP from *ephemeral* to *static*: Google Cloud Platform > Networking > VPC network > External IP addresses
- add an "A" record to static IP: domains.google.com > My Domains > Edit DNS
- the following are the commands run (I've used my real domain, not "example.com")...

commands

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www

cd /etc
sudo wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
sudo chmod a+x certbot-auto
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo cp 000-default.conf example.com.conf
```

The new **conf** file has this within:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've enabled the new Virtual Host file & reloaded

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

And at this point, I should be ready to run Let's Encrypt

```
sudo certbot --apache -d example.com
```

The error I get is:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:
   Domain: example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/MFEvXhKDwEPPKmNM1EyGky1YG9mAvH0e7i0Z_gqsbUc:
   "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
   <html><head>
   <title>404 Not Found</title>
   </head><body>
   <h1>Not Found</h1>
   <p"
   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I'm able to manually create the directory `/var/www/example.com/html/.well-known/acme-challenge`, and I can write files to it as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  I've been on this problem for 2 nights.

**Solution Update:** after following @RalfFriedl's answer to generate the SSL certificate, here are the steps to install that cert:

- create **conf** files for your port HTTP traffic and your HTTPS traffic

`cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo nano example.com.conf`

This **conf** file will have the following contents:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    # always redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

`sudo nano example.com-https.conf`

This **conf** file will have the following contents:

`<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>`

- Ensure you have SSL modules installed, then enable the new **conf**, and reload the Apache server

  `sudo a2enmod rewrite
  sudo a2enmod ssl
  sudo a2ensite example.com-https.conf
  sudo service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's Encrypt verifies that the domain is owned by you. To do that it will retrieve a file from an URL from your domain, in this case `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/MFEvXhKDwEPPKmNM1EyGky1YG9mAvH0e7i0Z_gqsbUc`. It seems certbot can't figure this out from your apache configuration.

Try this instead

```
sudo certbot --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/example.com/html -d example.com
```

Comment: Thank you, @RalfFriedl!

The exact command I used was `sudo certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/example.com/html -d example.com -d www.example.com --redirect` (needed to add the 'certonly' command)